# Enviar POX por jms desde wso2

Tags: wso2, activemq

Estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje hacia una cola en ActiveMQ y tengo un servicio spring-boot leyendo el mensaje de la cola pero le llegua un mensaje SOAP completo y yo solo quiero un mensaje de texto.

Es posible mandar un texto simple por jms desde wso2 sin que lo convierta a un mensaje SOAP?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="ADMINS.donaciones.request" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>        
                  . . . .         
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>                                                        
            <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>                  
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                        <Customer>
                            <address>
                                <street>NANTERRE CT</street>
                                <postcode>77471</postcode>
                            </address>
                            <name>Mary</name>
                            <age>37</age>
                        </Customer>                  
                </format>             
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="text" value="Error occurred while sending message"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" name="error code"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="message"/>
            </log>
            <makefault version="soap11">
                <code value="soap11Env:Server" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                <reason value="Error general en la mediacion"/>
                <detail>Algun error ha ocurrido en la mediacion del mensaje</detail>
            </makefault>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/json</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
</proxy>
```

Este es el proxy, y este es el mensaje que llega a mi app spring boot

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rcd="http://rcd.softel.cu">
<soapenv:Body>
<Customer xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<address>
<street>NANTERRE CT</street>
<postcode>77471</postcode>
</address>
<name>Mary</name>
<age>37</age>
</Customer>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Puede mostrar su código actual para poder ayudarle?

Comment: el codigo esta un poco  simplificado

Comment: dale un vistazo al final de este enlace: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Sample+252%3A+Pure+Text+%28Binary%29+and+POX+Message+Support+with+JMS